# Game enemy computer AI logic

Tags: java, loops

I am creating a battleships game. It is complete except for the enemy AI. At present, when the enemy hits a ship, it hits in another random place. Obviously this is not good so I have written a method to try and deal with this.

At present, it goes into a never ending loop if it misses the ship, after hitting it initially.

```
public void compAI() {
    // Randomly goes up, down, left, or right from the previous spot to attempt to sink ship

    // BEWARE, ARRAYLISTOUTOFBOUNDsEXCEPTION WAITING TO HAPPEN!
    // CURRENTLY CREATES NEVER ENDING LOOP IF IT MISSES............
    boolean compAllowed = false;
    int forwards = 0, up = 0;
    while (!compAllowed) {
        int direction = (int) Math.random() * 4;
        if (direction == 0) forwards = 1;
        if (direction == 1) forwards = -1;
        if (direction == 2) up = 1;
        if (direction == 3) up = -1;

        if (playerBoard[savedCompRow + up][savedCompCol + forwards] == '~') {
            playerBoard[savedCompRow + up][savedCompCol + forwards] = 'ø';
            //lastMove = "miss";
            compAllowed = true;
        }
        else if (playerBoard[savedCompRow + up][savedCompCol + forwards] == 'ø')
            compAllowed = false;
        else if (playerBoard[savedCompRow + up][savedCompCol + forwards] == 'X')
            compAllowed = false;
        else {
            playerBoard[savedCompRow + up][savedCompCol + forwards] = 'X';
            lastMove = "hit";
            compAllowed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Code for computer taking shot

```
public void compMove() {
    // Randomly choose locations
    boolean compAllowed = false;
    //if (lastMove.equals("hit")) compAI(); // Calls the compAI method to provide a smart strategy for the computer
    while (!compAllowed) {
        int row = (int) (Math.random() * boardSize);
        int col = (int) (Math.random() * boardSize);

        if (playerBoard[row][col] == '~'){
            playerBoard[row][col] = 'ø';
            compAllowed = true;
        }
        else if (playerBoard[row][col] == 'ø')
            compAllowed = false;    // Already made this move
        else if (playerBoard[row][col] == 'X')
            compAllowed = false;    // Already made this move
        else {      // Must be a hit
            playerBoard[row][col] = 'X';    
            /*
            lastMove = "hit";
            savedCompRow = row;
            savedCompCol = col;
             */
            compAllowed = true;
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: Where is the bit where it is a hit?

Comment: Im pretty sure that you want to set compAllowed to false when they miss

Comment: @MatthewRowlands sorry. I have added that method.

Comment: There is no protection against the random move going out of the playerBoard. But then, I would first add all coordinates that are potential targets in a list and randomly select on of them as the next try.

Comment: HINT: `(int) Math.random() * 4;` and `(int) (Math.random() * 4);` are *different* statements. You may want to try and look closer at *where* your AI makes the first strike.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should overthink the way your are generating random numbers.

```
int direction = (int) Math.random() * 4;
```

This statement is casting the value returned of `Math.random()`, which is a double out of the interval [0,1), to an integer. The result of this cast will always be 0. The multiplication with 4 happens afterwards, so `direction` gets always assigned 0.

I would recommend using the built-in Random-class. The class provides the overloaded method `nextInt()`. In your case, you can use it as follows:

```
Random random = new Random(); 
int direction = random.nextInt(4);
```

Where 4 is an upper bound. So you are creating random values out of the interval [0,4)

Edit: The use of the Random-class also avoids the necessary cast and errors from missing brackets can be avoided as well.